# NGX Translate core pipe not working with param

Tags: html, pipe, angular7, translate

I have 1032 Error that  contain this text: `"{0} USD"`

I want get this result: "5.15 USD", so  the span in html

```
<span>{{'1032' | translate: { '0': '5.15'} }}</span>
```

But the result is: `"{0} USD"`

Answer (score 0):

I have 1032 Error that contain this text: "{0} USD" ->
  so here the value in translation file should be

```
{
    "1032": "{{0}} USD"
}
```

So when we will use

```
<span>{{'1032' | translate: { '0': '5.15'} }}</span>
```

1032 -> {{0}}USD -> 5.15 USD